# MVVMCross ViewModel communicate with Android Service

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-service, mvvmcross

I need some help with architecture of a project. **I can't get how a ViewModel can communicate with an Android Service.**
I created an Inteface that can invoke some platform functions:

```cs
public interface IGeoLocationWatcher
{
    GeoLocation Location { get; set; }
    void StartLocationService();
    void StopLocationService();
}
```

And on android platform I use this interface like this:

```cs
[Service]
public class DroidGeolocationWatcher : Service,
    Android.Gms.Common.Apis.GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks,
    Android.Gms.Common.Apis.GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener,
    Android.Gms.Location.ILocationListener,
    IGeoLocationWatcher 
{
    public GeoLocation Location { get; set; }
    public void StartLocationService();
    public void StopLocationService();
}
```

When I get a new location, I invoke my custom message(event) that subscribe in ViewModel.
If the app runs in background I send a notification or when in foreground - I update my UI.

```cs
WeakSubscribe<GeoLocationChangedMessage> ((s)=> {
    Location = s;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Location);
});
```

But it seems it's not working. I need some advise what I'm doing wrong or an another approach.

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

The subscribe method returns a token of type `MvxValueEventSubscription<T>` You need to store that token on a property of your view model otherwise that token may get disposed prior to you receiving a notification.

if you want to stop receiving notifications, you can just do this:

```
if (this.token != null)
{
this.token.Dispose();
this.token = null;
}
```